# Connect 4 winning method

Tags: c#, forms

I've created this method to check for horizontal matches (then I will expand in vertical and diagonally) but the problem is that my method "triggers" only when there are 5 tiles on the same column, and I want to trigger when I have 4. This is the method I created. I'm using an 1 dimensional array. I can give you the whole code if you need it.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     Button[] gameButtons = new Button[42]; //array of buttons for  markers(red and blue)
    bool blue = true; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "Connect 4";
        this.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;

        for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            this.gameButtons[i] = new Button();
            int x = 50 + (i % 7) * 50;
            int y = 50 + (i / 7) * 50;

            this.gameButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            this.gameButtons[i].Name = "btn" + (index + 1);
            this.gameButtons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            this.gameButtons[i].TabIndex = i;
            //this.gameButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(index);
            this.gameButtons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.gameButtons[i].Visible = true;

            gameButtons[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.buttonHasBeenPressed(sender1, index);
            this.Controls.Add(gameButtons[i]);
        }
    }
    {
        var pressedButton = (Button)sender;
        //getLocation(sender);

        if (pressedButton.BackColor == Color.BlanchedAlmond)
        {
            var newBackColor = blue ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;

            var buttonToChangeIndex = index;

            while (buttonToChangeIndex + 7 < gameButtons.Count() && gameButtons[buttonToChangeIndex + 7].BackColor == Color.BlanchedAlmond)
            {
                buttonToChangeIndex += 7;  // Set to the index to point to this button.
            }

            gameButtons[buttonToChangeIndex].BackColor = newBackColor;

            blue = !blue;

            winCon(sender,index);
        }

private void winCon(object sender, int index)
    {
        int xLocation = index % Width;
        int yLocation = index / Width;
        int j = xLocation + Width * yLocation;
        bool end = false;

        for (int k = 50; k < 150; k = k + 50)
        {
            if (j + k != j)
            {
                end = false;
            }
        }
        end = true;

        if (end == true)
        {
            if (gameButtons[j].BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is a blue match");

            }
            if (gameButtons[j].BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is a red match");
            }
        }
}
```

Edit: Added the whole code.
Edit 2: I just realised. My code isn't even working as it should even with 5 tiles. Where ever I click with my mouse I get the message " There is a blue/red match". I was just testing it wrong.

Comment: Then I think your offending code needs to be added..  If you're using a 1d array, you maybe making your own life hard.

Comment: @BugFinder haha yeah I know but since I'm close to finish it I don't think I need to make it a 2D. I will post the code now.

Comment: I realise you maybe feeling you're near the end but your method of storing is whats  holding you back.. You've made it hard to tell if you're slotting a piece into a diagonal, or a horizontal or vertical line..  to be honest I dont see your winCon routine catering for all these eventualities.

Comment: @BugFinder So you're saying I should transition it in 2D?

Comment: This seems like a waste:         for (int k = 50; k < 150; k = k + 50)
        {
            if (j + k != j)
            {
                end = false;
            }
        }
        end = true; You set end to true, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what you want to do but `j + k != j` is always going to be true maybe you mean `gameButtons[j + k] != gameButtons[j]` and it doesn't matter anyway because the whole loop doesn't do anything `end = true;` is always going to be executed and the condition on the next if statement is going to be met maybe you mean to do this :

```
private void winCon(object sender, int index)
{
    int xLocation = index % Width;
    int yLocation = index / Width;
    int j = xLocation + Width * yLocation;
    bool end = true;

    for (int k = 50; k < 150; k = k + 50)
    {
        if (gameButtons[j + k] != gameButtons[j])
        {
            end = false;
        }
    }
    if (end == true)
    {
        if (gameButtons[j].BackColor == Color.Blue)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is a blue match");

        }
        if (gameButtons[j].BackColor == Color.Red)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is a red match");
        }
    }
}
```

also the code inside your loop is only going to be executed twice, for k=50 and for k=100, for k=150 the condition is not met.
good luck

Comment: If I do this I get an error when clicking that the index is outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: ok so you will have to check for that, in the loop add an if statement `if(j + k < width * hight) {if (gameButtons[j + k] != gameButtons[j]) { ... } }`

Comment: thanks I will check it soon, but will this do the work I wanted to do? I mean will it check for horizontal matches?

Comment: yes it will check for horizontal matches from the position of index, if you to check in the whole line then the code would be `if((ylocation * width) + k < width * hight) {if (gameButtons[(ylocation * width)  + k] != gameButtons[j]) { ... } }`

Comment: one more thing the `j` you have calculated is just the index you could just have put `j = index` instead of `j = xLocation + Width * yLocation;`

Comment: why did you choose 50,150,50 in your for loop (I find it weard) ? I can help you more if you explain your problem better

Comment: To be honest I don't really know, I was just experimenting cause I'm struggling to find a win condition for like 2 or 3 days and I thought this was (almost) working but in the end it didn't. So what I asked is just a silly question :)

Comment: btw i'm still getting the error that the index is outside the bounds of the array with the code you provided me. Probably because of the gameButtons[(yLocation * Width) + k] value.

Comment: I just want the for loop to check the whole column where the user places his button so I can check if there is a match of 4 tiles/buttons.

Comment: if you are still having an index out of bounds error that probably mean that the width and height aren't accurate or the index is out of bounds in the first place

Comment: what do you exactly mean with width and height? Cause right now the code calculates the width and height of the whole form which is 500x500

Comment: `if((ylocation * width) + k < width * hight) {if (gameButtons[(ylocation * width) + k] != gameButtons[j]) { ... } }` in this part of the code you can only have an index out of bounds exception if the `j` is grater than the array size and j is just equal to index then you have a problem in the first place or if `(ylocation * width) + k` is grater than the array size and that means width * height is grater than the array size because we made sure that (ylocation * width) + k is smaller than width * height

Comment: I can see you're not very familiar with working with matrices implemented by one dimensional array, my advice to you is to first convert your gameButtons array to 2D array and than start working on the solution. this will make your life easier

Comment: The array consists of 42 buttons starting from 0. The width * height is basically 500*500 so the gameButtons[(yLocation * width) + k] is outside of the bound of the array.

Comment: I just need a method that calculates the whole column (that the user placed his button) if there is a match of 4 of the same color or not but I'm getting confused by all that math and axis.

Comment: Or I just made a mistake and my code is currently wrong since you've changed a lot of things since the first one. Can you please re-write it in a good format so I could check please?